# How to detect WiFi network status in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, reachability

My app need to detect WiFi status changed in background, and I have use the logic as same as the Apple Sample 'Reachability'. When there's no sim card in device or turn off Mobile Data in 'Settings', then I turn on/off 'Wi-Fi' in 'Settings'. It can detect WiFi status well in background.

However, while turn on Mobile Data in 'Settings', it always can't work.

[image]

The following key code. When 'Mobile Data' is on, the function 'networkReachabilityCallBack' can't run.

```
if (proxyReachability) {
     NSLog(@"----setupNetworkReachabilityCallback------SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop");
    [LinphoneLogger logc:LinphoneLoggerLog format:"Cancelling old network reachability"];

    SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop(proxyReachability, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(proxyReachability);
    proxyReachability = nil;
}
proxyReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*)&zeroAddress);
if (!SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(proxyReachability, (SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack)networkReachabilityCallBack, ctx)){
    [LinphoneLogger logc:LinphoneLoggerError format:"Cannot register reachability cb: %s", SCErrorString(SCError())];
    return;
}
if(!SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(proxyReachability, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)){
    [LinphoneLogger logc:LinphoneLoggerError format:"Cannot register schedule reachability cb: %s", SCErrorString(SCError())];
    return;
}
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What do you actually want? You want to detect wifi that is connected or not OR you want to check that wifi is on or off?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jecky. Actually I want to detect wifi that is connected or not in background. When there's no sim card in iPhone or 'Mobile Data' is off, it can work well. If 'Mobile Data' is on, it always can't work but not every times.

Comment: http://www.enigmaticape.com/blog/determine-wifi-enabled-ios-one-weird-trick check out this link it may help you